# Why there is limited Map.of() values?

Tags: java

I recently started studying java lectures and there was a topic of collections. The lecturer said, "look at how the `Map.of()` method works and be horrified." I looked and I had a question: why is there no implementation in the form of `List<K>, List<V>`?

Below I have given the code and a screenshot of the debugger.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> integers = List.of(1, 2, 3);
        List<String> strings = List.of("a", "b", "c", "d");
        Map<Integer, String> mapOf = of(integers, strings);
        mapOf = null;
    }

    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> of(List<K> ks, List<V> vs) {
        return of(ks.iterator(), vs.iterator());
    }

    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> of(Iterator<K> ks, Iterator<V> vs) {
        Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();

        while (ks.hasNext() && vs.hasNext()) {
            map.put(ks.next(), vs.next());
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

[debug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLdqY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: Or `Map<Integer, String> mapOf = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(integers.size(), strings.size())).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(integers::get,strings::get));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it unlinks the keys and values. Given that you aren't using the `Map.of()` code that is already there, clearly then there are at least 11 k/v mappings you want to add (because if there are less than 10, just use `Map.of(k1, v1, k2, v2, ....)`.

That would look like:

```
Map<Integer, String> numberNames = Map.of(
  List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)),
  List.of("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve"));
```

That's visually speaking 'horrible' code (your lecturer really isn't doing you any favours by calling very carefully considered compromises "horrible"!) - I can't tell that `6` goes with `"six"`.

Contrast to:

```
Map.of(1, "one", 2, "two", 3, "three")
```

Where there is no chance I have troubles identifying that `2` and `"two"` are part of a pair.

More generally, writing a large (more than 10, that feels like 'large' is an apt word to use) set of constants in a source file **is a bad idea**. Sticking a ton of data in a source file is bad because you tend to run into the scenario where you want a non-programmer to be able to edit it, but they probably don't have the infrastructure on the devices and environments they use to properly test such a change, nor do you really want to tell them to just figure out where to add it in a source file. Also, class files have various limits that simply weren't designed with 'these are going to be multiple MBs worth of data, in a `.java` file' in mind either.

Instead, include a **data file** (such as a csv file) with the data, and then write java code that reads this in. Java already has a mechanism to load files from the same place classes are loaded, so the only way to make the argument 'but separate files are annoying and/or slow' is by also adding: '... and we are *SO* inexperienced at java we don't know how to use the available tools properly'.

Given these concerns, adding your proposed double-list implementation would actively be a bad idea. If I was in charge of team OpenJDK and this change request comes in, I would swiftly deny it. It hurts more than it adds (in that it enables a bad practice that has virtually no realistic use cases where a readily available alternative wouldn't be clearly better).

In the end, the answer to your question is simply: "Cuz they did not add it", asking "what was the reasoning behind this choice" is fraught with danger (it's kinda like asking: "What was da Vinci thinking about when they painted the mona lisa?"). I'm merely putting forward an obvious problem with having a method as you propose.